# Connecting to a K2 server without manually specifying username/password

Tags: k2

The examples of connecting to a K2 server in the K2 developer reference like [here](http://help.k2.com/onlinehelp/k2blackpearl/devref/current/webframe.html#Process_Instance_Connections.html) and [here](https://www.k2.com/onlinehelp/k2blackpearl/devref/4.6.7/webframe.html#Working_with_a_Process2.html) all involve setting a username and password in the connection parameters. Using this approach would mean I'd need to store a password in either plaintext or at best using two-way encryption, which is obviously not good practice.

Is there an alternative way, perhaps using a token, to establish these connections? It's hard to believe that every app using this functionality just stores a password somewhere, there are obvious security implications to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - I am not a K2 API expert, but I've come across it as a product, and do know for sure that it natively supports Windows Authentication. The same page, for which you provided the link, states the following -

```
connectionSetup.ConnectionParameters["Authenticate"] = "true";
connectionSetup.ConnectionParameters["Host"] = "LOCALHOST";
connectionSetup.ConnectionParameters["Integrated"] = "true";
connectionSetup.ConnectionParameters["IsPrimaryLogin"] = "true";
//connectionSetup.ConnectionParameters["Originator"] = "false";
connectionSetup.ConnectionParameters["Password"] = "{YourPassword}";
connectionSetup.ConnectionParameters["Port"] = "5252";
connectionSetup.ConnectionParameters["SecurityLabelName"] = "K2";
//connectionSetup.ConnectionParameters["SecurityPackage"] = "Kerberos,NTLM";
connectionSetup.ConnectionParameters["UserID"] = "{YourUserName}";
connectionSetup.ConnectionParameters["WindowsDomain"] = "{YourDomain}";
```

The third parameter here is `Integrated=true` and while the documentation is not explicit about it, I'd recommend to use this parameter, and try connect while ignoring the `user id` and `password`. **Assuming that K2 is configured for `Windows Authentication`**, it should work without having to provide explicit user name or password.. and certainly without need to store them yourself as a client of K2.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Integrated Security. K2 will then use the same user than the one currently logged in and you do **not** need to pass any credential.